# how can i distinguish ext3 and ext4 using superBlock structure?

Tags: partitioning, ext4, ext3

Is there any Flag or some byte in SuperBlock from which I can distinguish if it is an ext4 or ext3 File System?  I have already googled it and found some internal structures of ext3 & ext4, but can't find my answer.

[History of ext2, ext3, and ext4](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Frequently_Asked_Questions)
[SANS Digital Forensics and Incident Response Blog](https://digital-forensics.sans.org/blog/2010/12/20/digital-forensics-understanding-ext4-part-1-extents)

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you limit yourself to a flag in the superblock? There are tools that identify the file system type, can you just use one of them or do you need to do it manually by looking at bytes?

Comment: ext2 3 and 4 are the same filesystem. It is the OPTIONS that make the difference so yes you can use superblock to find the options but an ext4 filesystem with journaling set to off will be indentified as ext2 (and that is for any utility you use).

Comment: @Rinzwind Would you mind proof-reading my answer below?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's create two small disk image files `my-ext3` and `my-ext4` and format them in `ext3` and `ext4` respectively, so that we can test and see the differences:

```
truncate -s 10M my-ext3
mkfs.ext3 my-ext3

truncate -s 10M my-ext4
mkfs.ext4 my-ext4
```

Now the easiest way to check what they are is the `file` command:

```
$ file my-ext*
my-ext3: Linux rev 1.0 ext3 filesystem data, UUID=7ba99eb3-57c0-4d81-a2e7-529fdee64cbb (large files)
my-ext4: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=2308e0f8-443e-4164-b5ee-4810e9def008 (extents) (large files) (huge files)
```

As you can see, it correctly identifies each file system type. You can also examine the file systems with `fsck`, by mounting them or using some partitioning tools.

However, as *@[Rinzwind](https://askubuntu.com/users/15811/rinzwind)* pointed out in his [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/825667/how-can-i-distinguish-ext3-and-ext4-using-superblock-structure#comment1255124_825667), all `ext2`, `ext3` and `ext4` file systems are basically the same, except that the higher revisions support more file system features. Those do not directly tell you whether it is `ext3` or `ext4`, but you can check since which file system version each feature is available. If you find any `ext4`-only features, it must be `ext4`. Let's have a look at them.

The command to examine the file system is `dumpe2fs`. We are only interested in the superblock data, so we add the `-h` option, otherwise it will flood the console with tons of inode information as well. For us, only their "Filesystem features" are interesting, so let's use `grep` to filter that out:

```
$ dumpe2fs -h my-ext3 |& grep "^Filesystem features:"
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype sparse_super large_file

$ dumpe2fs -h my-ext4 |& grep "^Filesystem features:"
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
```

Now we have two lists of file system features and can check each of them to find out which is the lowest `ext?` file system revision that supports each feature. We can have a look at `man ext4` for that, it contains a list with all `ext4` file system features, their description and since when they are supported.

I made a little list for you and ordered the features by the first `ext?` revision that supports them. All features from older revisions are supported in newer revisions as well:

- **`ext2`:** `ext_attr`, `filetype`, `sparse_super`
- **`ext3`:** `dir_index`, `has_journal`
- **`ext4`:** `64bit`, `bigalloc`, `dir_nlink`, `extent`, `extra_isize`, `flex_bg`, `huge_file`, `meta_bg`, `mmp`, `uninit_bg`

There are more features described in `man ext4`, but without information about which file system revisions support them: `journal_dev`, `large_file`, `sparse_super2`, `quota`, `resize_inode`
Probably they are all present since `ext2`, but I'm not 100% sure. Please leave a comment if you know more about hem.

Comment: Looks good to me (but I do not claim to be an expert on filesystem ;-) )

Comment: @Byte Commander, thanks for your well explained answer, but still i have a little confusion. As I am working on a college project in C++ to identify the filesystem version like ext3 or ext4. In my module if we have a disk with 3-4 different linux volumes. I want to load the superblock structure , need to identify from that (In RAW mode) then  to pass the info to next module that how we need to read data from Inode (like need to process data pointers in extents(ext4) or in direct pointer(ext2/3) . As per my understanding i must get info from superblock only to read the file system data.

Comment: Maybe you should look into the source code of `dumpe2fs`, that's the tool I use above to examine the file system superblock. I can't tell you how it works behind the curtain and what raw binary structures you have in the superblock, but there you should be able to find it out.